# Can an arduino Uno control led, sound and smoke?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, communication, timers, rgb-led

I'm pretty new to this and I've not seen anyone answer this question yet - so I figured I would ask.

I have a vape mod that is set up to expel smoke with a trigger. I want to merge this trigger to the arduino so that the arduino can then have 2 single buttons. One would trigger a specific led set (8 LEDS), the vape mod, and sound through 2 external speakers for about 5 seconds. I'd like the second button would trigger another specific LED set (8), vape mod and sound (through two external speakers) for 3 seconds. I have acquired a 555 chip, which I've researched can control the timing of the triggers yet can't find anything about how much power is needed for these types of things.

If I'm able to have the LEDs, Sound, and Vape mod separately how do I combine these to control them all with a single push of a trigger?

However, again, the main thing I'm wanting to know is if an Arduino Uno can trigger all of these devices at a single time or if it would drain too much power?

Any help is truly appreciated! Also, if there is anything that you think I need to take into consideration that I haven't already - feel free to make suggestions. Like I said, I'm just starting out and I know I should start with simpler projects but I'm just really interested in whether or not this can be done.

All the best,

Comment: the arduino can most likely do all of that ... it is impossible to guess for sure because you have provided almost no information about the devices

Comment: An Arduino is a microcontroller. It can do all the logic for your project, including the timing. You won't need a 555 timer. However, the Arduino does not output enough current to drive an 8-LED strip or a smoke machine directly. You'll need an external power supply with enough current to drive those things, and will need to rig transistors to switch the power to those things on and off. A high current MOSFET transistor works very well for most DC applications.

Comment: If the load is inductive like a motor or relay, you'll likely need a "flyback diode" to protect the transistor from being fried by the surge of reverse current (back EMF) from the inductor. See this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode

Comment: You'll need to post a lot more details if you want concrete help.

Answer (score 1):

The arduino has more than enough **processing** power to manage those tasks mentioned. You probably won't need that 555. Playing music is possible as long as the arduino doesn't have to process the file itself. But switching on an external player is no problem (with what so ever circuitry).

The **electrical** power is another story, you probably will need extra power-supplies, but nobody can say without knowing your exact setup.

Comment: Thank you. I apologize.  Everything was delivered today. I can include the set up equipment once I get home. I appreciate the replies.